# Can I add a column to slickgrid on on the fly?

Tags: jquery, slickgrid

Is it possible to add an entierly new column to a slickgrid on the fly. I am trying to make a user buildable matrix and need them to be able to add columns as they build.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
var columns = grid.getColumns();
columns.push( columnDefinition );
grid.setColumns(columns);
```

With for instance

```
var columnDefinition = {id: "column1", name: "title", field: "column1", editor: Slick.Editors.Text};
```

Comment: .setColumns has a problem, it adds an additional stylesheet to the header, and when grid destroy operation is called, it does not clear the old ones. This gives an "Invalid Procedure call" exception in IE8.
@Tin correct me if I am wrong. Note:
In my case, I am calling setColumns on window resize even, that means it fires multiple times in very short duration.

Comment: It does clear all created styles on grid.destroy().  I suggest debugging your code to identify the actual issue.