# How can I only display 3 columns in my 13-column slick grid?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have slick grid in 10 columns .but i need to display only 3 columns only.how is it possible pls any one help me urgent.here my slick grid here slick grid code. This code display all columns default but i want to display only 3 columns.

**CSS**

```
.slick-row.selected .cell-selection {
    background-color: transparent; /* show default selected row background */
}
```

**HTML**

```
 <div style="position:relative">   
  <div style="width:600px;">
   <div class="grid-header" style="width:100%">
       <label>SlickGrid</label>
       <span style="float:right" class="ui-icon ui-icon-search" title="Toggle search panel"
                  onclick="toggleFilterRow()"></span>
    </div>
    <div id="myGrid" style="width:100%;height:500px;"></div>
    <div id="pager" style="width:100%;height:20px;"></div>   
  </div>

  <div class="options-panel">
   <b>Search:</b>
   <hr/>
     <div style="padding:6px;">
        <label style="width:200px;float:left">Show tasks with % at least: </label>          
          <div style="padding:2px;">
              <div style="width:100px;display:inline-block;" id="pcSlider"></div>
          </div>
          <br/>
          <label style="width:200px;float:left">And title including:</label>
          <input type=text id="txtSearch" style="width:100px;">
          <br/><br/>
          <button id="btnSelectRows">Select first 10 rows</button>
          <br/>
       <h2>Demonstrates:</h2>
        <ul>
           <li>a filtered Model (DataView) as a data source instead of a simple array</li>
           <li>grid reacting to model events (onRowCountChanged, onRowsChanged)</li>
           <li><b>FAST</b> DataView recalculation and <b>real-time</b> grid updating in response to data changes.<br/>The grid holds <b>50'000</b> rows, yet you are able to sort, filter, scroll, navigate and edit as if it had 50 rows.</li>
           <li>adding new rows, bidirectional sorting</li>
           <li>column options: cannotTriggerInsert</li>
           <li>events: onCellChange, onAddNewRow, onKeyDown, onSelectedRowsChanged, onSort</li>
           <li><font color=red>NOTE:</font> all filters are immediately applied to new/edited rows</li>      
           <li>Handling row selection against model changes.</li>
           <li>Paging.</li>
           <li>inline filter panel</li>
          </ul>
          <h2>View Source:</h2>
            <ul>
              <li><A href="https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/blob/gh-pages/examples/example4-model.html"
      target="_sourcewindow"> View the source for this example on
      Github</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>   
      </div> 
     </div>          
      <div id="inlineFilterPanel"          style="display:none;background:#dddddd;padding:3px;color:black;">  
      Show tasks with title including <input type="text" id="txtSearch2"> and % at least &nbsp;   
        <div style="width:100px;display:inline-block;" id="pcSlider2"></div>
      </div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
      <script src="slick.grid/lib/firebugx.js"></script>

      <script> var dataView; var grid; var data = []; var columns = [  
      {id: "sel", name: "#", field: "num", behavior: "select", cssClass:
      "cell-selection", width: 40, cannotTriggerInsert: true, resizable:
      false, selectable: false },   {id: "title", name: "Title", field:
      "title", width: 120, minWidth: 120, cssClass: "cell-title", editor:
      Slick.Editors.Text, validator: requiredFieldValidator, sortable:
      true},   {id: "duration", name: "Duration", field: "duration",
      editor: Slick.Editors.Text, sortable: true},   {id: "%",
      defaultSortAsc: false, name: "% Complete", field: "percentComplete",
      width: 80, resizable: false, formatter:
      Slick.Formatters.PercentCompleteBar, editor:
      Slick.Editors.PercentComplete, sortable: true},   {id: "start", name:
      "Start", field: "start", minWidth: 60, editor: Slick.Editors.Date,
      sortable: true},   {id: "finish", name: "Finish", field: "finish",
      minWidth: 60, editor: Slick.Editors.Date, sortable: true},   {id:
      "effort-driven", name: "Effort Driven", width: 80, minWidth: 20,
      maxWidth: 80, cssClass: "cell-effort-driven", field: "effortDriven",
      formatter: Slick.Formatters.Checkmark, editor:
      Slick.Editors.Checkbox, cannotTriggerInsert: true, sortable: true} ];

      var options = {   editable: true,   enableAddRow: true,  
      enableCellNavigation: true,   asyncEditorLoading: true,  
      forceFitColumns: false,   topPanelHeight: 25 };

      var sortcol = "title"; var sortdir = 1; var percentCompleteThreshold
      = 0; var searchString = "";

      function requiredFieldValidator(value) {   if (value == null || value
      == undefined || !value.length) {
          return {valid: false, msg: "This is a required field"};   }   else {
          return {valid: true, msg: null};   } }

      function myFilter(item, args) {   if (item["percentComplete"] <
      args.percentCompleteThreshold) {
          return false;   }

        if (args.searchString != "" &&
      item["title"].indexOf(args.searchString) == -1) {
          return false;   }

        return true; }

      function percentCompleteSort(a, b) {   return a["percentComplete"] -
      b["percentComplete"]; }

      function comparer(a, b) {   var x = a[sortcol], y = b[sortcol];  
      return (x == y ? 0 : (x > y ? 1 : -1)); }

      function toggleFilterRow() {  
      grid.setTopPanelVisibility(!grid.getOptions().showTopPanel); }


      $(".grid-header .ui-icon")
              .addClass("ui-state-default ui-corner-all")
              .mouseover(function (e) {
                $(e.target).addClass("ui-state-hover")
              })
              .mouseout(function (e) {
                $(e.target).removeClass("ui-state-hover")
              });



      $(function () {   // prepare the data   for (var i = 0; i < 50000;
      i++) {
          var d = (data[i] = {});

          d["id"] = "id_" + i;
          d["num"] = i;
          d["title"] = "Task " + i;
          d["duration"] = "5 days";
          d["percentComplete"] = Math.round(Math.random() * 100);
          d["start"] = "01/01/2009";
          d["finish"] = "01/05/2009";
          d["effortDriven"] = (i % 5 == 0);   }




        dataView = new Slick.Data.DataView({ inlineFilters: true });   grid
      = new Slick.Grid("#myGrid", dataView, columns, options);   grid.setSelectionModel(new Slick.RowSelectionModel());

        var pager = new Slick.Controls.Pager(dataView, grid, $("#pager")); 
      var columnpicker = new Slick.Controls.ColumnPicker(columns, grid,
      options); // columnpicker = new Slick.Controls.ColumnPicker(Columns,
      Grid, GridOptions); //grid.setSelectedcolumn([]);   // move the
      filter panel defined in a hidden div into grid top panel  
      $("#inlineFilterPanel")
            .appendTo(grid.getTopPanel())
            .show();

        grid.onCellChange.subscribe(function (e, args) {
          dataView.updateItem(args.item.id, args.item);   });


        grid.onAddNewRow.subscribe(function (e, args) {
          var item = {"num": data.length, "id": "new_" + (Math.round(Math.random() * 10000)), "title": "New task",
"duration":
      "1 day", "percentComplete": 0, "start": "01/01/2009", "finish":
      "01/01/2009", "effortDriven": false};
          $.extend(item, args.item);
          dataView.addItem(item);   });

        grid.onKeyDown.subscribe(function (e) {
          // select all rows on ctrl-a
          if (e.which != 65 || !e.ctrlKey) {
            return false;
          }

          var rows = [];
          for (var i = 0; i < dataView.getLength(); i++) {
            rows.push(i);
          }

          grid.setSelectedRows(rows);
          e.preventDefault();   });

        grid.onSort.subscribe(function (e, args) {
          sortdir = args.sortAsc ? 1 : -1;
          sortcol = args.sortCol.field;

          if ($.browser.msie && $.browser.version <= 8) {
            // using temporary Object.prototype.toString override
            // more limited and does lexicographic sort only by default, but can be much faster

            var percentCompleteValueFn = function () {
              var val = this["percentComplete"];
              if (val < 10) {
                return "00" + val;
              } else if (val < 100) {
                return "0" + val;
              } else {
                return val;
              }
            };

            // use numeric sort of % and lexicographic for everything else
            dataView.fastSort((sortcol == "percentComplete") ? percentCompleteValueFn : sortcol, args.sortAsc);
          } else {
            // using native sort with comparer
            // preferred method but can be very slow in IE with huge datasets
            dataView.sort(comparer, args.sortAsc);
          }   });

        // wire up model events to drive the grid  
      dataView.onRowCountChanged.subscribe(function (e, args) {
          grid.updateRowCount();
          grid.render();   });

        dataView.onRowsChanged.subscribe(function (e, args) {
          grid.invalidateRows(args.rows);
          grid.render();   });

        dataView.onPagingInfoChanged.subscribe(function (e, pagingInfo) {
          var isLastPage = pagingInfo.pageNum == pagingInfo.totalPages - 1;
          var enableAddRow = isLastPage || pagingInfo.pageSize == 0;
          var options = grid.getOptions();

          if (options.enableAddRow != enableAddRow) {
            grid.setOptions({enableAddRow: enableAddRow});
          }   });



        var h_runfilters = null;

        // wire up the slider to apply the filter to the model  
      $("#pcSlider,#pcSlider2").slider({
          "range": "min",
          "slide": function (event, ui) {
            Slick.GlobalEditorLock.cancelCurrentEdit();

            if (percentCompleteThreshold != ui.value) {
              window.clearTimeout(h_runfilters);
              h_runfilters = window.setTimeout(updateFilter, 10);
              percentCompleteThreshold = ui.value;
            }
          }   });


        // wire up the search textbox to apply the filter to the model  
      $("#txtSearch,#txtSearch2").keyup(function (e) {
          Slick.GlobalEditorLock.cancelCurrentEdit();

          // clear on Esc
          if (e.which == 27) {
            this.value = "";
          }

          searchString = this.value;
          updateFilter();   });

        function updateFilter() {
          dataView.setFilterArgs({
            percentCompleteThreshold: percentCompleteThreshold,
            searchString: searchString
          });
          dataView.refresh();   }

        $("#btnSelectRows").click(function () {
          if (!Slick.GlobalEditorLock.commitCurrentEdit()) {
            return;
          }

          var rows = [];
          for (var i = 0; i < 10 && i < dataView.getLength(); i++) {
            rows.push(i);
          }

          grid.setSelectedRows(rows);   });


        // initialize the model after all the events have been hooked up  
      dataView.beginUpdate();   dataView.setItems(data);  
      dataView.setFilterArgs({
          percentCompleteThreshold: percentCompleteThreshold,
          searchString: searchString   });   dataView.setFilter(myFilter);   dataView.endUpdate();

        // if you don't want the items that are not visible (due to being
      filtered out   // or being on a different page) to stay selected,
      pass 'false' to the second arg   dataView.syncGridSelection(grid,
      true);

        $("#gridContainer").resizable(); }) </script>
```

Comment: Format your question.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way is to only add the 3 columns you want to be visible to the "columns" variable.

If you want to show more columns at a later time you can add more columns on the fly (refer to this stackoverflow question on how to do this: [Can I add a column to slickgrid on on the fly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4463176/can-i-add-a-column-to-slickgrid-on-on-the-fly) )

**Update:**  Example to only show the first 3 columns

insert this line:

```
columns = columns.slice(0, 3);
```

before the following line:

```
grid = new Slick.Grid("#myGrid", dataView, columns, options);
```

Comment: thanks....


Now the grid is display all columns ..i need option to display only 3 columns if i want to display another columns means i need thats options

Comment: I updated my answer with an example. Does this help you?

Comment: thank u so much...its working fine..now i got grid display i need other columns if i need to display that option all.i need checkbox list that all columns once i want i selected that checkbox means need to enable that selected columns also .any idea

Comment: am new for slick grid now my slick grid is getting all checkbox is selected list i want to select checkbox manually how can i do this pls any one help me.